# XCode scrolls to top when i press esc

Tags: xcode

Whenever i press esc to see the auto-fill options, the code window scrolls right to the top. Any ideas how to stop this from happening?

Answer (score 1):

Check your Key Bindings in Preferences. There may be a second action defined for the Escape key.

You probably have the Escape key defined for the action "Scroll to Beginning of Document." Use the Search bar in the Key Bindings section to search for "Scroll."